# How to redirect http requests for subpages on domain to another different address using iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

I have setup 
`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.8.1:200` 
`iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
`-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT`
`-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Where i'm running a virtual host server on apache at 192.168.8.1:200 Working fine, pages get redirected fine but only top level domain requests eg.  `www.google.com`, this gets redirected to `http://localhost/`.

BUT: The problem is requests to eg `www.google.com/subpage` or `www.anotherPage.com/subdir/subsubdir/page`, this causes a 404 error from apache. I want it to redirect even these subpage requests to the root at localhost.

CAVEAT: I could set up htaccess rewrite rule but it would cause problems as it would redirect requests to `http://localhost/subdir/subpages` too. Seeing as i don't want this, what would be a reasonable suggestion?

Comment: You don't do this at the firewall level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spurred by @Hauke Laging 's answer, I made sure .htaccess was in the folder i wanted i.e `/var/www`, I wrote this code:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f#if the requested is non existent as a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d#if the requested is non-existent as a dir
RewriteRule (.*) / [L]`

and all is fine now. If i request non existent files or directories, i get redirected to root. Keeping in mind i still have my NAT settings, now anyone on my wifi gets taken to my local home page. . . regardless of what they type into the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` redirects only what you want it to. You just have to to it right.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =!localhost [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://localhost/
```

Comment: %{HTTP_HOST}  for me = localhost because of DNAT. The requests eg for samledomain.com/directory/page are DNAT-ed to an equivalent of localhostIP/directory/page. Hence i keep getting 404 error page not found from my apache because the /directory found on sampleomain.com is not also found on my localhost site structure.

Comment: @DudusBlack `HTTP_HOST` is a header line and not affected by DNAT at all.

Comment: Alright. My folder structure: I have /MySite/all_of_its_Subdirs within /var/www/html. I have tried your suggestion but still if i request for www.anyPage.com/ASubDir, even with your settings, i get 404 error, "/ASubDir" was not found on this server(i.e localhost). I'm guessing NAT is working but not htaccess? Allow_Override in .conf is OK, PS: If i misform my RewriteRules i get an error, an indication that the .htaccess is geting consulted.  @Alxs

Comment: @DudusBlack I have not used the `=!localhost` pattern yet. You may try `www.anyPage.com` instead. And you can increase the log level. Above a certain value you get log messages for the rewrite rules, too.